# ImportError: No module named google.cloud

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am unable to import google.cloud.speech

```
from google.cloud import speech
```

I have installed it using :

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech -t dir-name
```

It is giving me below error while importing it from dir-name

```
ImportError: No module named google.cloud
```

google package with all the sub package is present over there but without **__init__**.py in every sub packages as well.

How can I import this packages without adding **__init__**.py in package folder?

PS : I have also tried from **__future__** import absolute_import, but its not working.

Comment: I also have the same error - creating dedicated virtual environment helped.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech` and `from __future__ import absolute_import` worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: for me it was  absolute impor - 
pip install google-cloud-dialogflow

Answer (score 30):

The instructions on the "Cloud Speech API Client Libraries" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) are now valid and the install is successful, as desired.

I installed the library for Python on my Debian machine using the command:

`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech`

Comment: Right answer. You need to tweak the command to install other google-cloud package. For example for me it was `pip install google-cloud-storage`

Comment: Not really @Astariul  (March 2023)

Answer (score 27):

use this:

```sh
pip install google-cloud-bigquery
```

Comment: and if running in a notebook, restart kernel and reimport

Answer (score 7):

I used `sudo python -m pip install google-cloud` instead and it worked.

Comment: The specific libraries seem to need to be specified now.  "google-cloud-*"

Answer (score 6):

"No module named google.cloud" you need a python environment for google cloud.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
<your-env>/bin/pip install <google-cloud>
```

`<google-cloud>` replace this with required library. e.g: google-cloud-vision or google-cloud-storage, etc

`<your-env>` is a folder name, which is going to be store all python environment related things inside your project.

Comment: It is not mandatory to use a python environment for Google Cloud.

Answer (score 4):

After many hours with the same problem, I discovered the solution: Import the library "get_messages" before importing something from "google.cloud". This worked in Python 3:

```
from google.api_core.protobuf_helpers import get_messages
from google.cloud import speech
```

Comment: this solved google.cloud,  but now I ger "No module named 'google.api_core'"

Answer (score 4):

The google.cloud is deprecated post June 18, you should install specific extension of your package

```
pip install google-cloud-{x}
```

Use

Source: [github discussion](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2366#issuecomment-418724574)

Comment: @nishith please mark a solution as complete if it solves your request

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
$ cd google-cloud-python/speech
$ python setup.py install
```

According to [Ref](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2515).

Answer (score 1):

After you install `google-api-python-client`,
you have to specify what exact google cloud product you want to install.

So for pubsub it is:

```
$pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-pubsub
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem recently. 2 things solved it for me:

Installing the following packages

```
google-api-core==1.22.1 
google-auth==1.20.1
google-cloud-texttospeech==2.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
graphviz==0.13.2
greenlet==0.4.16
grpcio==1.31.0
gTTS==2.1.1
gTTS-token==1.1.3
```

If this doesn't work, try switching to Python 3.7

Comment: I resolved this issue by using python3 on the command line (3.7.3)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem just recently. My error was caused because I hadn't enabled the Cloud Speech-to-Text API. I was able to do that in cloud console and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

type this command:

```
 pip show google-cloud
```

you should ee an output like this:

```
Name: google-cloud
Version: 0.34.0
Summary: API Client library for Google Cloud
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-publisher@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\<user>\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

then take the full location path and add it to PATH (env vars)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

with requirements .txt content being

```
google-cloud-datastore==1.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the installs mentioned here helped me. Then I did the following and it worked:

pip install google-cloud-logging

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-logging/

Answer (score 0):

This problem disappeared for me when I used a virtual env. My fix looks like this:

```
-#!/usr/bin/python3
+#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

FYI I'm using Python 3.8.3 on a MacBook. I didn't see this error with the same code on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Python version you have try:

```
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-speech
```

or

```
python -m pip install google-cloud-speech
```

Answer (score 0):

For future seekers, in my case i was using a folder named `google`. So this was conflicting with the lib. For this case, you just need to change the folder's name (i.e.: `googlelib`)

```py
#from
from google import blabla # this "google" is from your folder

#to
from googlelib import blabla
```