# BigQuery on Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I need to run BigQuery on Python but the Google BigQuery module doesn't exist

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project='PROJECT_ID')
query = "SELECT...."
dataset = client.dataset('dataset')
table = dataset.table(name='table')
job = client.run_async_query('my-job', query)
job.destination = table
job.write_disposition= 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job.begin()
```

Do you guys know how to do the connection?

Comment: what you mean the module doesn't exist? what error are you seeing?

Comment: Agree with Willian - we need to see the error. Did you install `bigquery`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named cloud while using google.cloud import bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469762/no-module-named-cloud-while-using-google-cloud-import-bigquery)

Comment: On ImportError: No module named google.cloud . Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397506/importerror-no-module-named-google-cloud)    . #Suggestion - Its worth spending few mins searching your question on web or SO before asking, Most of the time its already answered somewhere else!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you do not have bigquery module installed, you could install it with -

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

Ref - [Installing the client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

Answer (score 1):

As per [Document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries), need to install client library for bigquery.

Comment: tks, found it: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you need to correct is to setup credentials to connect your big query with PYTHON. You will also need to setup environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing towards the location of your credential file .

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is on the connection to BigQuery:
`client = bigquery.Client()` creates the connection using your default credentials. Default credentials can be set on terminal using `gcloud auth login`. More on that you can see here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login

If your problem it to install the library, consider running on terminal `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery` -- library docs can be found here: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late to the party but you can try using below command

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

This command generate Application Default Credentials (ADC) for your personal account and then you can use local clients by invoking
`bigquery.Client(project='PROJECT_ID')` same goes for other GCP services also. This will be by default available in google cloud shell.