# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google‘ when requesting paramaterized query

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I’ve been running into the same error code when trying to use Python 3.7 to query data from BigQuery. I have enabled the API and also followed instructions on which client libraries to download using the terminal on my MacOS.

I’m not sure what the issue is but each time I try to input the code `from google.cloud import bigquery`, it returns this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google‘`

I am very new to these environments, including python and am not familiar with setting up `$PATH` for running my parameterized query. A sample of what I’m trying to run could be found here: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/35627d145a41d57768f19d4392ef235928e00f72/samples/client_query_w_named_params.py

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: did you follow the installation instructions from https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/tree/35627d145a41d57768f19d4392ef235928e00f72#installation ?

you'll need to have a virtual environment with the google module installed and activated (nothing to do with $PATH)

to verify if you're working on the environment you can do ```which python```.  (it should point to the environment that you created)

to verify if you have google module: ```python -c 'from google.cloud import bigquery' ``` (only verify if the module is there by importing it, no action is done here).

Answer (score 1):

Try install the package again with :

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`
you might want to use `python` instead of `python3`, depending on your setup

Had the same error as your, this worked on MacOS

p.s: cannot post to comment due to insufficient reputation

See also: [ImportError: No module named google.cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397506/importerror-no-module-named-google-cloud)